# Hibernate get items that don't have children

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

Supose I have an object Foo that contains a list of Bars.
If I create an alias on the Bar class for my Criteria, I only receive the items that actually have Bars.

```
criteria.createAlias("bars", "bars");
```

Now, if I want to have alle the Foos that have no Bars, I would have to create my alias with a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

```
criteria.createAlias("bars", "bars", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
```

Now, my Foo class has an enormous amount of children (that have children, that have children, ...). Do I now have to LEFT_OUTER_JOIN them all or is there an other solution so that my list is complete instead of my list only containing the Foos with proper children?

Comment: Using a left outer join wouldn't mean you get only those without children but you get them _as well_. You'd have to add another condition i.e. count(children) = 0 or children = null (or similar).

Comment: Exactly what I want. I want both those with and without children. So the only solution is to left outer join them all?

Comment: Probably yes, although I don't know criteria that well, but I guess you'd have to specify the join type on all joins (except for fetch joins). If you have multiple joins in your query they probably serve some purpose other than restricting to those with children only. If that's the only reason and you remove that you probably want to remove the joins in general.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved this problem by doing a LEFT OUTER JOIN on each of my children.

```
criteria.createAlias("bars", "bars", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
```